# Use Hbase with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-hadoop

Is there a sample project show how to use hbase in spring boot ?
I read this link [How to use hbase with Spring Boot using Java instead of XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795097/how-to-use-hbase-with-spring-boot-using-java-instead-of-xml). But the instruction is not detail enough.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple demo project for using hbase in spring boot application without xml. And has answered the other related question you mentioned.

This demo mainly depends spring-data-hadoop and hbase-client.

gradle dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop:2.5.0.RELEASE'
compile('org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.3.1'){
    exclude group :'log4j',module:'log4j'
    exclude group :'org.slf4j',module:'slf4j-log4j12'
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
}
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
```

Configure the hbase connection parameters in spring boot's application.properties (No XML!):

```
spring.data.hbase.zkQuorum=192.168.0.109:2181
spring.data.hbase.zkBasePath=/hbase
spring.data.hbase.rootDir=file:///home/hbase-1.2.2
```

class HbaseProperties.java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.hbase")
public class HbaseProperties {
    // Addresses of all registered ZK servers.
    private String zkQuorum;

    // Location of HBase home directory
    private String rootDir;

    // Root node of this cluster in ZK.
    private String zkBasePath;

    // getters and setters...

}
```

HbaseConfig.java, inject the configurations into the HbaseTemplate:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HbaseProperties.class)
public class HbaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private HbaseProperties hbaseProperties;

    @Bean
    public HbaseTemplate hbaseTemplate() {
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", this.hbaseProperties.getZkQuorum());
        configuration.set("hbase.rootdir", this.hbaseProperties.getRootDir());
        configuration.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", this.hbaseProperties.getZkBasePath());
        return new HbaseTemplate(configuration);
    }

}
```

Service class, we can use the configured HbaseTemplate now:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.zql.hbasedemo.vo.Quote;

@Service
public class FeedService {
    @Autowired
    private HbaseTemplate hbaseTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test(){
        Quote quote = new Quote();
        quote.setEventType("ft");
        quote.setHandicap("4");
        quote.setMarket("OU");
        quote.setMatchId("27350208");
        quote.setSelection("OVER");
        quote.setPrice("1.93");
        saveQuote(quote);
    }

    public void saveQuote(Quote quote) {
        hbaseTemplate.put("quotes", quote.getMatchId(), "data", quote.getMarket() + ":" + quote.getSelection(),
            quote.getPrice().getBytes());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no sample project that does this. I think it would be great to have and would be a greatly appreciate contribution to the Sample project - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/

We recently added a plain HBase with XML sample, but it isn't using Spring Boot. maybe a rewrite to use Boot and @Config would be doable.